# How do I get a set "this" to a variable in a component in angular2 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component. Inside I have the following:

```
constructor() {
  this.something = "Hello";
}

document.addEventListener('click', doSomething());

function doSomething(e) {
   console.log(this.something) // this is undefined
}
```

I want to make it so that I can access this.something inside of the doSomething(e). Usually I would just create a variable outside and use var self = this; then reference self.something to get to that "Hello". Unfortunately in angular 2, I am getting errors with self not being defined, etc. How can I access this.something inside of the event listener I created?

Comment: And where's that `doSomething` defined? Please, provide the context for the code you're posting. The snippet above will throw syntax error. Because `constructor` is outside of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lambda function to get correct **this**

`document.addEventListener('click', () => doSomething());`

Comment: It is not obvious what is the lexical scope of `doSomething`. It has a good chance to not get 'correct this'. The problem the question wasn't specific enough at the moment of posting, and bad questions result in bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with Angular, instead of adding an event listener to the document directly, is the `@HostListener` function decorator. Below is a sample. [More information](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#06-03).

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(event) : void {

    event.stopPropagation();

    if(...) {
        console.log(this.something);
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, I don't know your whole situation, but something like this could be of use to you.